# Opening existing Excel file libxl

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, ios, excel

Using the example project of libxl for IOS, I am trying to open an exsisting xls file in the bundle

```
BookHandle book = xlCreateBook();
xlBookLoad(book,"Beta-1.xls");    
SheetHandle sheet = xlBookGetSheet(book,0);
NSLog(@"%@",sheet);
```

It always returns null, could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, or is this even possible.

Is there any alternatives, I have spent a good few hours looking, must be IOS compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Posting against this old thread for reference and to answer specifically the question of using LibXL to read an XLS or XLSX formatted file. The below code demonstrates how to read an excel file using LibXL and prints the content (value) and type (number, string, bool...) of each cell.

```
// Get the path to the excel file to be opened
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" ofType:@"xlsx"];

// Convert the path into a const char * from an NSString
const char *file = [path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Create a handle for the excel book (XLSX)
// Use xlCreateBook() for XLS file format
BookHandle book = xlCreateXMLBook();
xlBookLoad(book, file);

// Authorize full use of the library (uncomment below and change values)
//xlBookSetKey(book, "REGISTERED_NAME", "PROVIDED_KEY");

// Determine if the excel file handle is valid
if(xlBookLoad(book, file)){
    // We have the book now get the first sheet in the book
    SheetHandle sheet = xlBookGetSheet(book, 0);

    // Ensure the sheet has been opened as is valid
    if(sheet){
        // Get the first and last rows of the sheet (determines the length of the parse)
        for (int row = xlSheetFirstRow(sheet); row < xlSheetLastRow(sheet); ++row){
            // Get the first and last columns of the sheet (determines width of the parse)
            for (int col = xlSheetFirstCol(sheet); col < xlSheetLastCol(sheet); ++col){
                // When reading the cell pull the type (bool, int, string...)
                enum CellType cellType = xlSheetCellType(sheet, row, col);
                FormatHandle format = xlSheetCellFormat(sheet, row, col);
                NSLog(@"(row = %i, col = %i) = ", row, col);

                // Determine if the cell has a formula or is a value w/ format
                if (xlSheetIsFormula(sheet, row, col)){
                    const char* s = xlSheetReadFormula(sheet, row, col, &format);
                    NSLog(@"%s %s", (s ? s : "null"), "[formula]");
                } else{
                    // The cell is not a formula therefore print the value and type
                    switch(cellType){
                        case CELLTYPE_EMPTY: NSLog(@"%s", "[empty]"); break;
                        case CELLTYPE_NUMBER:{
                            double d = xlSheetReadNum(sheet, row, col, &format);
                            NSLog(@"%f %s", d, "[number]");
                            break;
                        }
                        case CELLTYPE_STRING:{
                            const char* s = xlSheetReadStr(sheet, row, col, &format);
                            NSLog(@"%s %s", (s ? s : "null"), "[string]");
                            break;
                        }
                        case CELLTYPE_BOOLEAN:{
                            bool b = xlSheetReadBool(sheet, row, col, &format);
                            NSLog(@"%s %s", (b ? "true" : "false"), "[boolean]");
                            break;
                        }
                        case CELLTYPE_BLANK: NSLog(@"%s", "[blank]"); break;
                        case CELLTYPE_ERROR: NSLog(@"%s", "[error]"); break;
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

xlBookRelease(book);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that you're using an invalid literal to log your newly created value (you have no pointer).  %@ is the ObjC object literal, so you're going to want to use `cout` instead.

Comment: What do you mean?  #include <stdio> and use cout like a normal function.  Xcode doesn't just do one language.

Comment: My bad, I'm forgetting my basic c++.  It's in iostream.  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: Same problem, do I need to include a library as well?

Comment: Are you doing this in a .m, .mm, .c, or .cpp file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20076/discussion-between-blakey87-and-codafi)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at libxls on sourceforge? There is a objc framework for it specifically for iOS.

Comment: Hey David, yes I have tried but cant get it to compile, off topic but Im currently using your dhxls for reading excel files, its great!, do you have an updated IOS version for writing.

Comment: Well, you didn't say you were trying to WRITE a file - right, xlslib isn't updated for ios now. From what I read about libxl, it appears its updated regularly to read and write - something a commercial library can do.